# MATLAB Matrix Multiply Efficiency

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, matrix, efficiency

I am using MATLAB to prototype a few matrix multiply techniques and compare efficiency. Eventually, I will move the prototype codes to C. It is for a homework assignment where we need to write an efficient matrix multiply routine (by being aware of cache size, locality, etc.).

I am curious about the efficiency differences between these two very similar loops:

**Matrix Multiply Loop 1**
- sum over columns of A times elements of B -> column of C

```
function [C] = dgemm_naivepe( A,B,C,n )

for j=1:n
    tempcol=zeros(n,1);
    for k=1:n
        for i=1:n
            tempcol(i)=tempcol(i)+A(i+(k-1)*n)*B(k+(j-1)*n);
        end
    end
    for k=1:n
        C(k+(j-1)*n)=tempcol(k);
    end
end
```

end

**Matrix Multiply Loop 2**
- sum over columns of A times elements of B -> column of C

```
function [C] = dgemm_naivepe( A,B,C,n )

for j=1:n
    for k=1:n
        for i=1:n
            C(i+(j-1)*n)=C(i+(j-1)*n)+A(i+(k-1)*n)*B(k+(j-1)*n);
        end
    end
end

end
```

After several test runs of various matrix sizes, I found that **Loop 1** is faster than **Loop 2**. Could someone help me understand why this is?

PS: I posted this on a general coding stack exchange but didn't get much of a response, so I figured I could post it here as well.

Comment: I wouldn't trust timings that come out of MATLAB. There's many other things involved that make its timings not indicative of well-optimized C code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop 2 does not [preallocate](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html?requestedDomain=true) $C$. Hence it gets resized $n$ times, which requires many reallocations. Try adding `C = zeros(n, n)` before the for loops.

[EDIT: so does the first one, so probably this isn't the true reason.]

(That said, I second [ChrisRackauckas's comment](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html?requestedDomain=true) --- there is little point in testing timings under Matlab at this level.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the size of C vs the size of tempcol is what is making the difference?
If it is pulling the C matrix into cache it has to make more room than for tempcol, possibly removing data from A and/or B which wouldn't have been removed for the smaller tempcol.

Comment: The weird thing is that the C accesses should be contiguous in memory, just like the accesses of tempcol. But yeah, I would guess it has something to do with that, just not sure exactly how it works.